# Format XML generated by Xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to format the output XML generated by Xstream, to make it more readable. Currently, a newline is added after each element but I would like newline to be added after every attribute. Is there a way to do this?

Pretty Print Writer is used by default to format the output of the xml but this doesn't suffice for me. I want newline to be added after every

Comment: http://xstream.codehaus.org/manual-tweaking-output.html

Answer (score 4):

XStream includes a `PrettyPrintWriter`

After building your XStream...

```
XStream xstream = //...whatever
```

Instead of:

```
// p is my object needing xml serialization
xstream.toXML(p)
```

Use something like this to make it pretty:

```
BufferedOutputStream stdout = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
xstream.marshal(p, new PrettyPrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdout)));
```

Comment: So, how could I tell it to indent with, say... four spaces? I can't seem to be able to find a method for this? Is this supported?

Comment: @carlspring Use the alternative constructor that takes an indentation chararray, e.g. `new PrettyPrintWriter(writer, new char[]{' ', ' ', ' ', ' '})`

Comment: @aetheria: Thanks, I came across exactly that solution myself.

Comment: This does not work if you are using the Stax driver.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at their tutorial on [tweaking the output](https://x-stream.github.io/manual-tweaking-output.html).

Comment: I have seen that tutorial but it didn't help.

Comment: Thank you @GáborLipták - the link has been fixed

Comment: Wow. That was fast :D

Answer (score 1):

I've used this to :

```
        xstream= new XStream(new DomDriver());
```

But it's not so efficient than StaxDriver()