# How to indent XML with XStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I would like to be able to set the indentation to a number of spaces when storing with XStream. I have seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943000/format-xml-generated-by-xstream) and I'm afraid it's not quite clear how to set the number of spaces to use. I seem to not be getting something. Could somebody kindly explain this and illustrate it with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example in the post you've linked to and the [API](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/xml/PrettyPrintWriter.html), I came up with this code:

```
char[] indent = new char[] { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };
BufferedOutputStream stdout = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
xstream.marshal(object, new PrettyPrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdout), indent));
```