# XStream no new lines in output (output is one line)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I want to serialize an ArrayList of Objects with Xstream. It works, but the whole output is written in one line. My code looks like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
String target = fc.saveFile("xml", "Choose where to save your events");
if (!target.contains(".xml"))
    target += ".xml";
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(target)) {
    xstream.toXML(FooList.getFooList(), fw); //// this returns an ArrayList<Foo>
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><list><foo><id>0</id> [...] </foo></list>
```

Well everything is written in one line. Any idea how to change this? I just want to have a standard format like:

```
<list> 
  <id>
    ....
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943000/format-xml-generated-by-xstream) could be helpful.

Comment: Already saw this one. Sadly no help. It seems like the standard-output should be with new lines, but for me it isn't

Comment: Ok got the answer... The problem was XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver()); Should be instead XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

Comment: neza, you should add that as an answer and accept it (you are allowed to accept your own answer to your own question). That way people know the question is solved and should anyone have the same issue they can quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the answer... The problem was

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
```

Should be instead

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
```