# What's the lightest xstream convertion?

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I'm using [XSTREAM](http://x-stream.github.io/) to serialize my messages in my application.

I see that there's more way to generate [COMPACT MESSAGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894625/how-to-disable-pretty-printingwhite-space-newline-in-xstream) in xstream but i need to know which is the lightest (talking about memory) method to convert my messages.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different drivers like JettisonMappedXmlDriver and DomDriver. Of all those, JettisonMappedXmlDriver would be more efficient.

Comment: JettisonMappedXmlDriver converts message into json form, which has lower length as compared to xml and hence efficient in terms of memory.